# wmuSlider causing problems in IE10

Tags: jquery, css

This is my first attempt at posting a question here so fingers crossed - and please be kind.

I am using wmuSlider on a site I am building - this is not yet full styled but is working as I want in Chrome and Firefox but for some reason it is not displaying in IE10 - could someone please let me know why this might be please.  The slider in question can be found on the link below.

http://www.justg.co.uk/smg

Thank you in advance

G

Comment: check your console, there is one error, try to resolve it first even it could not be related to your slider's issue

Comment: .wmuSliderWrapper is set to display:none in CSS rules. Remove it show slider. So, looks like the logic to show it (using js/jquery) is not called in IE.

Comment: IE might have problems (that other browsers are ignoring) as the markup on the page [is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.justg.co.uk%2Fsmg%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)